What is the purpose of this circuit inside a solar lamp?
I'm trying to get started with electronics, just as a side quest. I found this little circuit inside a solar lamp I had. I'm trying to understand what its purpose is and why it uses its components, mainly because I'm just curious, but also to point me at what to learn next.
This is the circuit:

(The three diodes are laid in the opposite direction to the other two)
I am aware of the function and working of every component in this circuit, separately. I don't understand the overall purpose of this circuit, that's what I'd really appreciate help on. :D
I've put everything I need explained in points.
The wiring looks like this:

I tried analyzing it myself, but failed. I can't remember where the connections were and that's part of what made it difficult.

I'd love to have a diagram to follow, with an explanation of how the circuit works.

Here's the back of the PCB:

One thing I realized I'd have to learn is what S+ and S-. I came up with "sense". I didn't understand the concept.

I'd appreciate if someone could explain sense and why they're also present in addition to the regular +- input within the context of this circuit, to make it easier to understand the concept. Failing that, I'll settle for a good reading recommendation.

The components in the lamp were; this circuit, a solar power source, but also a cable to plug into a socket (just in case), batteries, and the light emitting component itself.
The way the lamp depended on this was:

The LED indicated that the lamp was being charged.
There was a plug that connected to the cable for charging. This was also connected to the circuit, but broke off.
I'm assuming there were wires that were connected to the circuit from the solar cell, but I don't know where.

I'd love to know about this basic circuit to whet my curiosity and also to cement a few abstract topics I need to learn about.

Please add some photos with front lighting so we can see what the components are.

shadow components ... it is unclear why you think that the pictures show useful detail

I'd hoped someone could figure out the circuit from the wiring. I'd quite forgotten about the diodes and that their alignment wasn't clear. Is this better?

Most of the circuit is a capacitor dropper. This design is non-isolated, so it should only be used when the circuit can't be touched.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_power_supply

The large rectangular component in your picture is C1. The tubular component is C2.
The components on the right side may not exist in your module. For your application, regulation isn't necessary.
If you want to learn more, you should carefully trace your circuit to see how it compares to this example.

I believe it's something like this (values may be different and 120VAC/60Hz mains assumed).
D1..D4 form a bridge rectifier. C2 is a capacitive dropper (an impedance in series with the bridge). R2 is a bleed resistor to discharge C2 so it does not give the user a tingle after power has been removed.
D5 isolates the battery, C1 smooths the power a little bit. It's not clear why they chose to return R1 to that  side of D1 rather than the other- maybe just to ease the single-sided PCB layout - the other side would work too, but with a higher value for R1. Below you can see where I've assumed a battery would be attached.There is some current for a trickle charge and the LED gets sufficient average current to be visible. When the power is removed the LED current drops to zero (it does not discharge the battery).


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Note: the ground is there so the simulation will work. There is no ground apparent in the actual circuit.

You're too good! This answer deserves all the votes. It helped me understand everything.Thanks so much for putting in your time!
